# Simple Date Format

Tags: java

I have so simple question. Although I spent couple of hours, I could not find the solution of the problem but I am sure that there is a small trick that I do not know.

```
if(selectJob.getType() == 'G'){
    long tardy = Long.parseLong(offSetValue);
    Timestamp gleichzeitig = new Timestamp(dateBegin.getTime()+ tardy);
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String simulDate = simpleDateFormat.format(gleichzeitig);
    atnajsonJobLine.add(simulDate);                         
}
```

tardy number and date_begin are taken from the user via GUI. Although in debugged mode, I saw that I managed to add tardy number into the begin date but in the console it is simply written begin date.

//Expected output:

beginDate: 13:10:00
tardy: 10

simulDate : 13:10:10

//Actual: 
13:10:00

Could someone help me?
Advance thanks.

Comment: You're adding 10 milliseconds... you appear to have expected it to mean 10 seconds.

Comment: @limonik I suggest you to take a look at naming conventions ("date_begin")

Comment: @ScriptKiddy I edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Timestamp` is based on milliseconds.

Adding 10 will result in the same seconds (and 10 milliseconds more).

If you print milliseconds you can see.

Try to add 10 * 1000 instead of 10.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding 10 milliseconds. Try this ->

```
if(selectJob.getType() == 'G'){
    long tardy = Long.parseLong(OffSetValue);
    Timestamp gleichzeitig = new Timestamp(date_begin.getTime() + tardy * 1000);
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String SimulDate = simpleDateFormat.format(gleichzeitig);
    atnajsonJobLine.add(SimulDate);                         
}
```